# Updating datasource from datagridview - concurrency violation

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've a DataGridView that has a binding source that's tied to a table sitting on  SQL Server .

Upon a user modifying a datagridview cell and tabbing or clicking to another cell, I use the CellEndEdit event to update my DataSource (SQL table).

```
 Private Sub dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
    '****** UPDATING underlying database when user exits cell
    EwosappendixbindingSource.EndEdit()
    EwosappendixTableAdapter.Update(PIMUserDBDataSet.ewosappendix)
End Sub
```

As this works well on occasion a user will get a

"concurrency violation: the updatecommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records“” 1

In the cases where the error was thrown, only one user was in the datagridview making a change.  They clicked in a cell, modified it's content, and then clicked out of the cell.

With my understanding of what triggers this error, my first question is, why was the error thrown and how can I catch or prevent the error from happening.

thanks,

Jim

Comment: How about posting the schema of the PIMUserDBDataSet.ewosappendix. It seems that something is happening there. Maybe an auto increment field or unique index...

Comment: ewosappendix is a data table filled using a table adapter.  The underlying source is a table on an SQL Server.  One field on the table has a unique key assigned.  The table adapter only allows select and update. Insert and delete have been turned off.  Updates can occur on a select number of fields and not all including the key field.  Hope this helps.  I've not been able to recreate the error, and it's difficult for the user to identify the exact conditions when it happens.